# Rhythmbox - rating from mp3 file

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3

The metadata in an mp3 file can contain the rating set by the user. A music player like Clementine can access and store the rating within the mp3 file.

How can I get Rhythmbox to read (and preferably also store) the rating within the mp3 file?